# Android - No Resource Found that matches the given name Errors

Tags: android

I am learning android and I have downloaded an open source app named Astrid and was deploying in eclipse. I got the "No resource found that matches the given name"@string/name_hint". I checked the Strings.xml and found that this label was not available in there. There is another file called String-legacy.xml and in that this value is set. Eclipse is not referring to string-legacy.xml and throwing these errors.

I copied the values from strings-legacy.xml and pasted it to strings.xml and this error was removed. I am sure this is not the right approach...there should be some setting for me to tell eclipse to read from string-legacy.xml

anybody have any thoughts on the same, please advice. Thanks

Harry